# jqModal jQuery Plugin - How to Set Timeout on Modal Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqmodal, modalpopups

I'm using the jQuery Plugin [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).

New to it, so i'm still learning its usage.

What i'm trying to do is show the popup for say 3 seconds, then automatically close.

Basically, here is the flow of events i want:

1. My page loads.
2. Show modal popup saying "Connecting to MySite.."
3. (after 3 seconds) modal popup automatically closes.
4. Refresh page (window.location.reload());

Here's what i have so far (it's not much):

HTML:

```
<div id="jqPopupModal" style="display: none;">Connecting to My Site...</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
   showPopup();
   window.location.reload();
}

function showPopup() {
   $('#jqPopupModal').jqm( { modal: true } );
   $('#jqPopupModal').jqmShow();
}
```

Is there some argument i can pass to the .jqmShow() function to set a timeout for the window? Or should i hook into the onShow callback and do a simple setTimeout?

It would also be nice if step 2 and 4 happens asynchronously: in other words, page refreshes whilst jQuery popup is shown.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Okay so i've got the open/close delay working, but not with the `window.location.reload()`. Putting that is causes no delay to happen at all.

Here's my code:

```
function fbcPopupOnShow() {{
                $('#fbcModalPopup').show();
                window.location.reload();
                window.setTimeout(new function() {{
                    $('#fbcModalPopup').jqmHide();

                }}, 1000);
            }}

            function showFacebookConnectPopup() {{
                $('#fbcModalPopup').jqm( {{ 
                    modal: true,
                    onShow: fbcPopupOnShow
                }});

                $('#fbcModalPopup').jqmShow();
            }}
```

I was hoping `window.location.reload()` would reload the parent window WHILST the popup is being shown, not one or the other.

**EDIT 2:**

Figured out cant do the reload and popup asynchronously, as the jqModal popup isnt really a "popup" (i.e a new window is NOT spawned). It's just a hidden DIV.

Therefore i've just changed my code to do the reload AFTER the window is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onShow event to close it after a delay (requires jQuery 1.4+), otherwise you can just use javascript timeouts to close the popup.

```
var autoClose = function(hash) { $('#jqPopupModal').delay(3000).jqmHide(); }; 
$('#jqPopupModal').jqm({ modal: true, onShow:autoClose});
```

Comment: Yep, that's what ive been trying. That works, (open window, close), etc. But trying to get it to work with window.location.reload() is causing problems. Updated question.